# Conditional email recipient based off Shipping Method

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, email

Basically i'm trying to get my function to change the New Order Recipient conditionally based off the Shipping method (i.e. Local Pickup Option #1 and #2)

The problem is my function is my `if`statement. It will always go to the `else`

```
function conditional_email_recipient( $order, $recipient ) {


    $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
    if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
        return $recipient; 
    }


    if ( 'local_pickup:1' == $order->get_shipping_method ) {
      $recipient = 'local1email@gmail.com';




    } else {
      $recipient = 'local2email@gmail.com';


    }

    return $recipient;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

I've tried changing the `local_pickup:1` to other possible shipping method names, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

====================================================

**Here's my final working code**

It's a bit sloppy but it's working perfectly as intended.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );

function conditional_email_recipient( $recipient ) {

    $methodTest = wc_get_order();

     $shipping_method_id = $methodTest->get_items('shipping');

    foreach($shipping_method_id as $el){
        $order_shipping_method = $el['method_id'];

    if ( 'local_pickup:1' == $order_shipping_method ) {
      $recipient = 'localPickup1recip@gmail.com';


    } else {
      $recipient = "localPickup2recip@gmail.com";


    }


    }

    return $recipient;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `get_shipping_method` is a function. You seem to be using it as a variable.

Secondly `$order->get_shipping_method()` returns Shipping method label, which you're trying to compare with id.

Now you can either compare Titles, or use

```
$order->get_items( 'shipping' );
```

which returns an array with `name`, `type`, `method_id`, `cost` and `taxes`, and use `method_id` for comparison.